# Float enum and aggregate class

Tags: c#, .net

I have to create `walet` class, where i count how many `coins` it has, so:

```
enum Coins {
    OneCent = 0.01f,
    FiveCent = 0.05f,
    OneDollar = 1.0f
}
```

and:

```
public class RowQuantity<T> {
    public T entity;
    public int Quantity;
}
```

and my walet:

```
public class Walet {
    public List<RowQuantity<Coins>> CoinsCash;
    public Walet() {
        this.CoinsCash.Add(new RowQuantity<Coins> { entity = Coins.OneCent, Quantity = 25 });
    }
}
```

The problem goes here:

I can't have `enum` with float value => so, i have to declare it as a static class.

```
public static class Coins {
    public const float OneCent = 0.01f;
    public const float FiveCent = 0.05f;
    public const float OneDollar = 1.0f;
}
```

But in this way, i can't pass `static` type as `instance` of generic class.

So, how could i realise this? (List with quantity of float enum values)

Comment: How about having a `non-static` class with constants?

Comment: `Decimal` is a much choice for monetary objects due to lack of rounding issues.

Comment: @Rohit Vats, It could be, but how should i pass it in `List.Add`?

Comment: @psubsee2003, `enum` can't have `double` value, as i know

Comment: Well, nearly. It can have any integral type.

Comment: @FSou1 The decimal suggestion was not an answer to your problem, just a general observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to avoid rounding issues, you need to use `decimal`. Secondly, you need to make it an instance class that shows some static properties that are `OneCent`, `FiveCent` and `OneDollar`, like so:

```
public sealed class Coins
{
    private decimal _num;
    private Coins(decimal num)
    {
        _num = num;
    }
    public static readonly Coins OneCent = new Coins(0.01M);
    public static readonly Coins FiveCent = new Coins(0.05M);
    public static readonly Coins OneDollar = new Coins(1M);
    //add more properties like this
}
```

Comment: Ok, could you show me please, how i should pass this class into `List.Add()` method? Something like this: `List.Add((new Coins()).OneCent, 25);` ?

Comment: @FSou1 Just List.Add(Coins.OneCent). Where does the 25 come from?

Comment: I mean this line: `this.CoinsCash.Add(new RowQuantity<Coins> { entity = Coins.OneCent, Quantity = 25 });`

Comment: I can't access `Coins` because it's not static class, so, i have to init this before?

Comment: @FSou1 `Coins` in this answer does not have a public constructor.  You don't initiate it.  It is exactly like your static class idea in the question except it has been converted to an instance class so you use it as a generic type constraint.

Comment: @FSou1 When you use it it will be inited. Just try accessing it like a static class.

Comment: @FSou1 This is basically what enums do internally. The static members are the enum values, private decimal is where the data is stored, and you can only instatiate it inside the same class because the constructor is private.

Comment: Yeah, but my question was nearly about `static` keyword. I thought before, that i have to use `static` with class if i need to access to `static` property, but as i can see, i haven't to declare class as `static` if i need a `static` property. Thx!